# "ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor" in spring-cloud-aws-context 2.2.6.RELEASE? upgrade from version 1.2.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I was using the `ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor.java` class from the `spring-cloud-aws-context:1.2.1.RELEASE` in my @Configuration class in my Spring Boot/Batch project (spring-boot-starter version 2.4.X):

```
    @Bean
    public static ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor resourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor(@Autowired AmazonS3 amazonS3Client) {
        return new ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor(amazonS3Client);
    }
```

I recently upgraded spring-cloud to version `2.2.6.RELEASE` and this class is missing:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor
  location: package org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.support.io
```

Is there a replacement for this in the newer spring cloud verions?

**Javadoc:**
https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-context/1.2.1.RELEASE/index.html

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue?